# Possible Index/Match Formula.

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below, is a snippet of data from a larger data set. Whereas the first column below is not actually first column in data set so VLOOKUP will not work.

What I'm trying to accomplish is if G:G then return H in column I. So in the example below since "6862C" is listed above I'd like "4510 Not Billable" to return to cell I4. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely best done with VBA. 
Technically, you can solve this anyway, but there are some things to think about either way.
You have to do a lot of searching. Last duplicate, the account of that duplicate, the number of that account and so on. And if you display the new account in `I` instead of `H` then you also have to search through that column.

I've written my most crazy (for me) function yet for this and it's probably very badly written. But you can solve this example by using the following as an array:

```
=IFERROR((LEFT(INDIRECT("H" & MAX(ROW($1:3)*($G$1:G3=G4))),FIND(" ",INDIRECT("H" & MAX(ROW($1:3)*($G$1:G3=G4))))-1)+1 &" "& RIGHT(INDIRECT("H" & MAX(ROW($1:3)*($G$1:G3=G4))),LEN(INDIRECT("H" & MAX(ROW($1:3)*($G$1:G3=G4))))-FIND(" ",INDIRECT("H" & MAX(ROW($1:3)*($G$1:G3=G4)))))),"")
```

As an array formula, you have to press `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter` when entering the formula. This is meant to go in `I4` and will autofill down accordingly.

**However** it would only work for the first duplicate, since it's only checking the `H`column. If you instead put this into `H4` it would work much better when adding more duplicates.

Sorry if this code-mash is silly.